# BERT document embedding

Tags: python-3.x, embedding, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I am trying to do document embedding using BERT. The code I use is a combination of two sources. I use [BERT Document Classification Tutorial with Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eSGWNqKeeY&t=2080s), and [BERT Word Embeddings Tutorial](https://mccormickml.com/2019/05/14/BERT-word-embeddings-tutorial/). Below is the code, I feed the first 510 tokens of each document to the BERT model. Finally, I apply K-means clustering to these embeddings, but the members of each cluster are TOTALLY irrelevant. I am wondering how this is possible. Maybe something is wrong with my code. I would appreciate if you take a look at my code and tell if there is something wrong with it. I use Google colab to run this code.

```
# text_to_embedding function
import torch
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

def text_to_embedding(tokenizer, model, in_text):
    '''
    Uses the provided BERT 'model' and 'tokenizer' to generate a vector
    representation of the input string, 'in_text'.

    Returns the vector stored as a numpy ndarray.
    '''

    # ===========================
    #   STEP 1: Tokenization
    # ===========================

    MAX_LEN = 510

    # 'encode' will:
    #  (1) Tokenize the sentence
    #  (2) Prepend the '[CLS]' token to the start.
    #  (3) Append the '[SEP]' token to the end.
    #  (4) Map tokens to their IDs.
    input_ids = tokenizer.encode(
        in_text,                         # sentence to encode.
        add_special_tokens = True,       # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
        max_length = MAX_LEN,            # Truncate all sentences.
        #return_tensors = 'pt'           # Return pytorch tensors.
    )

    # Pad our input tokens. Truncation was handled above by the 'encode'
    # function, which also makes sure that the '[SEP]' token is placed at the
    # end *after* truncating.
    # Note: 'pad_sequences' expects a list of lists, but we only have one
    # piece of text, so we surround 'input_ids' with an extra set of brackets.
    results = pad_sequences([input_ids], maxlen=MAX_LEN, dtype="long",
                          value=0, truncating="post", padding="post")
    
    # Remove the outer list.
    input_ids = results[0]

    # Create attention masks.
    attn_mask = [int(i > 0) for i in input_ids]

    # Cast to tensors.
    input_ids = torch.tensor(input_ids)
    attn_mask = torch.tensor(attn_mask)

    # Add an extra dimension for the "batch" (even though there is only one
    # input in this batch)
    input_ids = input_ids.unsqueeze(0)
    attn_mask = attn_mask.unsqueeze(0)


    # ===========================
    #   STEP 1: Tokenization
    # ===========================

    # Put the model in evaluation mode--the dropout layers behave differently
    # during evaluation.
    model.eval()

    # Copy the inputs to the GPU
    input_ids = input_ids.to(device)
    attn_mask = attn_mask.to(device)

    # telling the model not to build the backward graph will make this
    # a little quicker.
    with torch.no_grad():

        # Forward pass, returns hidden states and predictions
        # This will return the logits rather than the loss because we have
        # not provided labels.
        outputs = model(
            input_ids = input_ids,
            token_type_ids = None,
            attention_mask = attn_mask)
        

        hidden_states = outputs[2]

        #Sentence Vectors
        #To get a single vector for our entire sentence we have multiple 
        #application-dependent strategies, but a simple approach is to 
        #average the second to last hiden layer of each token producing 
        #a single 768 length vector.
        # `hidden_states` has shape [13 x 1 x ? x 768]

        # `token_vecs` is a tensor with shape [? x 768]
        token_vecs = hidden_states[-2][0]

        # Calculate the average of all ? token vectors.
        sentence_embedding = torch.mean(token_vecs, dim=0)
        # Move to the CPU and convert to numpy ndarray.
        sentence_embedding = sentence_embedding.detach().cpu().numpy()

        return(sentence_embedding)


from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
# Load pre-trained model (weights)
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
                                  output_hidden_states = True, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
                                  )
model.cuda()

from transformers import BertTokenizer

# Load the BERT tokenizer.
print('Loadin BERT tokenizer...')
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', do_lower_case=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it solves your problem but here's my 2 cent:

- You don't have to calculate the attention mask and do the padding manually. Have a look at the [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.__call__). Just call the tokenizer itself:

```py
results = tokenizer(in_text, max_length=MAX_LEN, truncation=True)
input_ids = results.input_ids
attn_mask = results.attention_mask
# Cast to tensors
...
```

- Instead of using the average of the second to last hidden layer, you can try the same thing with the last hidden layer; or you can use the vector represents `[CLS]` from the last layer

Comment: How to use the vector represents `[CLS]` from the last layer. What changes do I need to make in above code?